# What elastic search request body is equivalent to URI search?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I made a request using the URL:

```
http://myserver/stuff/stuff/_search?q=TEST
```

Then what is the equivalent document that I would POST to that endpoint without a query string?

I've tried:

```
{
  query: {
    term: { "_all": "TEST" }
  }
}
```

But with how our indexes are set up this doesn't return anything (but `?q=TEST` does). [The most basic search example in the API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-request-query.html) specifies a field to search against and I don't want to do that. I want to search as open ended and unrestricted as if I had used the query string.

Comment: What I understood from your post, you don't want to use query string.

Comment: @Richa No I do not. I am trying to post my search query but have the same results as if I had used the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_4), an URI search query string query (i.e. `q=...`) is equivalent to sending a `query_string` query in the body.

So this

```
curl -XGET http://myserver/stuff/stuff/_search?q=TEST
```

is equivalent to this

```
curl -XPOST http://myserver/stuff/stuff/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "TEST"
        }
    }
}'
```

Both queries will default to searching against the `_all` field, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> q is The query string (maps to the query_string query, see Query
>   String Query for more details.

From the documentation.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-uri-request.html

This is the corresponding query DSL:

```
{
  query: {
    "query_string": { "_all": "TEST" }
  }
}
```

Also relevant:

> The default field for query terms if no prefix field is specified.
>   Defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in
>   turn defaults to _all.